# Create a package installer for a daemon on OSX

Tags: macos, mono, pkgbuild

I am working on porting a daemon from Linux to OSX.  The daemon itself is written in C# and executed with Mono.  I am trying to create an installer package for the daemon that is installed into the directory "/Library/MyAppSuite/MyDaemon" and contains the typical bin, lib, etc directories.  A symlink is then installed into the /Library/LaunchDaemons to have it start on boot.  During the pkgbuild step:

```
pkgbuild --root /tmp/MyDaemonComponent.dst --component-plist MyDaemonComponent.plist MyDaemonComponent.pkg --install-location /Library/MyAppSuite/MyDaemon
```

I get the error saying "Not a valid bundle".

How do I go about creating the package so that it installs into the correct directory and will run the postinstall script?  Having an install wizard (that doesn't allow changing the install location) would also be nice.

Comment: I really wish you have an answer here, please.